# Gmail is trimming html email content. How to avoid the issue?

Tags: gmail, trim

Gmail introduced a trimming feature in emails for "better readability". This causes a lot of pain for me, as I have a notification system for email, where I send some html email messages to users. Basically email looks like this:

```
divs and styling
Object alert in Project by User
tables and tr/td
User Action on Object in Project
/tables and tr/td
/divs and styling

link
footer
```

To group all emails in one conversation, first email has subject, subsequent emails have Re: subject.

Active users can receive significant amounts of emails like this, but due to "better readability" feature, ALL of the email content (starting from second email) is suppressed.

I am looking for advice - maybe I should redesign my html, or gmail has some anti-suppression code, or just a hack to go around this issue.

Issue from users perspective is described here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=756b83fa60ca1df7&hl=en

Comment: I think it would be easier to help you if you'd provide the entire HTML of two messages, and maybe a screenshot of what happens.

Comment: hi, if i were you i'd try to play with the email till i figured out what makes them recognize the email as a continuation of the previous one and then try to change it. maybe different emails should have different subjects, or maybe the subject is unrelated... i will not hold my breath for them to fix it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I had the trimming problem occurring on a table of an HTML newsletter.
>   It was very important that the entire table display because it was the
>   #1 content our client wanted to communicate. Here's the fix, or at least here's how we solved our problem. **We eliminated any repetition.**
>   So for this table, the lines in between each row, Gmail was seeing the
>   lines as repetitive. So I altered the pixel width by 1 px every other
>   line, which eliminated the repetition and fixed our problem. So that
>   said, look for repetition, and try to remove it. OR in some cases, you
>   might have to add type (in white) to create the variation.
>
> [Source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/yoAlDr3PyN4/E3BcD4CtnhQJ).

**PS**: This is a bit unrelated, but I stumbled upon this question while looking for a way to disable the content trimming and keep the conversation view at the same time. I didn't find anything, so I developed a small extension for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trimless-for-google-mail/niepjjjfafhadmfdminbckmciijcaagc) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/trimless-for-google-mail).

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that there is a very simple rule which causes this behaviour: Gmail will clip the email as soon as it sees the sender (`From:`) name in the body of the message, regardless of where this appears.

Solution: **make sure that that the `From:` name in your email is not used in the message body** (except in the signature, which will probably get clipped!).

Comment: What a dumb rule (though it occurred to me that might be the problem long after the fact)... Surely it's not uncommon for a sender's name to appear in his email, Google?

Answer (score 2):

This is an awful *bug* in Gmail, if you're unlucky enough to get bitten by it.

In my case, it was "trimming" an *entire* message, in a *clean thread*. [See an example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm98B.png), noting that the "trimmed" content is expanded in the screen-shot.

I ultimately worked around Gmail's bug by removing the entire header you see in that example ("Awesome Home Swap"), including the border below it. I stopped short of actually trying to figure out what *specifically* was making Gmail confuse that header as a "signature" (though I suspect it could have been the border, implemented using CSS directive `border-bottom:1px dotted grey` to style the `<td>` element).

Comment: By the way, [this reference](http://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-trimming-signature/28762/) may be of some value.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution that worked wonderfully for me. Simply create a bunch of hidden unique images throughout your emails to provide uniqueness to parts of the email that aren't actually unique. I'm building my emails with React so I have this `Unique` components that I'm using pretty much everywhere:

```
import * as React from "react"

function random() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 10000000).toString()
}

class Unique extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        return (
            <img style={Unique.style} src={`data:image/png;base64,${random()}`} />
        )
    }


    static style = {
        visibility: "hidden",
        display: "none",
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        color: "transparent",
        background: "transparent",
    }
}
```

One thing I like about this solution is that it doesn't mess up the email preview text that would otherwise happen if you're using hidden text.

Answer (score 0):

Add a double hyphen **--** *before* the collapsed part. I was able to wrap it in a  with font color matching the background. Worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the emails Gmail sent. Adds the following code (spacer.gif).

I guess this is the solution.

```
            <img alt="" height="1" width="3" src="https://notifications.google.com/g/img/AD-FnEztup4OClDshQhMVXDbi6Oi0lSN-FgEY1jyW384aotccA.gif">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```